# Unzip string with Ruby

Tags: ruby, gzip

I have compressed gzip data (object->array of objects->json->gzip) emitted with python to rabbitMQ. If I catch it with python - I is being decoded easily.

Encoding python function:

```
def gzip_str(string_):
    out = io.BytesIO()

    with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=out, mode='w') as fo:
        fo.write(string_.encode())

    bytes_obj = out.getvalue()
    return bytes_obj
```

Decoding python function:

```
def gunzip_bytes_obj(bytes_obj):
    in_ = io.BytesIO()
    in_.write(bytes_obj)
    in_.seek(0)
    with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=in_, mode='rb') as fo:
        gunzipped_bytes_obj = fo.read()

    return gunzipped_bytes_obj.decode()
```

The thing is - I have to decode it on logstash, so it should be done with ruby. 
Tried different approaches, all similar to this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# encoding: utf-8
require 'bunny'
require 'base64'
require 'zlib'
require 'stringio'


connection = Bunny.new
connection.start

channel = connection.create_channel
queue = channel.queue('kit_logstash', :durable => true)


begin
  queue.subscribe(block: true) do |_delivery_info, _properties, body|
    puts body
    puts body.encoding
    puts Base64.decode64(body)
    puts Base64.decode64(body).encoding

    body_decoded = Base64.decode64(body.to_s)
    sio = StringIO.new(body_decoded)
    gz = Zlib::GzipReader.new(sio)
    result = gz.read.to_s
  end
rescue Interrupt => _
  connection.close

  exit(0)
end
```

Message on rabbitMQ looks like this:

```
H4sIAAuxGFwC/4uuVkrNTczMUbJSUMpyyNJLzs9V0lFQSs7PK0lMLgGJgrh5ibmpILYXkC4GCRRnZ+bkFAOFopW0DRXMzS0sLS0NDAzMlWKBkqkppUCZaqXS
dLCCgMqSjPw8sEwBRMQ5WCm2tlZHYeDsjgUA6yqlo/gAAAA=
```

And it can be decoded also easily using some online decoders.

But ruby is not handling it in any way
It sees whether something like this:

```
T\x93\x10D\xFA\xCAQ\x03\xC9\xF8\x82\xF2\x82\x06\xE3\xB4\xB0\xFD]Q\x9A
```

Or something like this:

```
��-,--VJ�M��Q�RP�r��K��U�QPJ��+IL.���y��� ��.   gg������
```

And of course it says `Zlib::GzipFile::Error: not in gzip format`
Am I doing something wrong? Maybe its something with encodings? Or string-bytes difference?

Comment: `Zlib::GzipReader.new(StringIO.new(Base64.decode64('H4sIAAuxGFwC/4uuVkrNTczMUbJSUMpyyNJLzs9V0lFQSs7PK0lMLgGJgrh5ibmpILYXkC4GCRRnZ+bkFAOFopW0DRXMzS0sLS0NDAzMlWKBkqkppUCZaqXSdLCCgMqSjPw8sEwBRMQ5WCm2tlZHYeDsjgUA6yqlo/gAAAA'))).read` results in : `"[{\"email\": \"j@j.com\", \"contact\": \"\", \"name\": \"James\", \"skills\": [\"+1 7789990007\"], \"edu\": {\"ug\": [\"Python\"], \"pg\": [\"CS\"]}}, {\"email\": \"j@j.com\", \"contact\": \"\", \"name\": \"James\", \"skills\": [\"+1 7789990007\"], \"edu\": {\"ug\": [\"Python\"], \"pg\": [\"CS\"]}}]"`

Comment: Yeah, thanks. But seems like ruby is not seeing the same base64 string (which I can see manually inside RMQ dashboard). It sees that \xYY\xYY string somehow.

Comment: Hmm, could it be that bunny is decoding the base64 for you for some reason?

Comment: If so - seems like it is doing it wrong, because I should unzip message the same way without base64decoding. I'll take a deeper look at bunny

Comment: I guess when reading from IO the wrong encoding is used. It assumes a certain string encoding while in reality another encoding is used. For example Ruby thinks the encoding is UTF-8 while in reality it is UTF-16le or something. You can force Ruby into a specific encoding with [*String#force_encoding*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/String.html#method-i-force_encoding).